# Django migration OperationalError: index [name] already exists

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I hope someone can help me.
I have three environments as part of my django development lifecycle, dev, uat and live.  Django 3.2.6 with python 3.9.6.

I'm trying to add a couple of fields to two of my models but I'm getting an error when I try to migrate the **live** database, the dev and uat database migrations worked fine.

Here is the migration code, generated by `makemigrations`

```
    # Generated by Django 3.2.6 on 2022-01-26 21:33
    
    from django.db import migrations, models
    
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
        dependencies = [
            ('tasks', '0015_activity_next'),
        ]
    
        operations = [
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='activity',
                name='delegated',
                field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
            ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='activity',
                name='notified',
                field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
            ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='adviser',
                name='digest',
                field=models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Send digest of assigned activities once per day?'),
            ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='adviser',
                name='email',
                field=models.EmailField(default='i.pigney@tpio.co.uk', max_length=254),
            ),
        ]
```

Nothing complex, just adding two fields to my Activity Model and another two fields to my Adviser model.
I wasn't expecting any problems but... here is the error traceback:

```
$python manage.py migrate
...
Running migrations:
  Applying tasks.0016_auto_20220130_1904...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: index tasks_activity_provider_id_1557b363 already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 330, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 303, in _remake_table
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.../projects/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index tasks_activity_provider_id_1557b363 already exists
```

The error message is clear but I don't understand why the existence of an index in the database should be a problem.  That same index already exists in the dev and uat databases and that didn't cause a problem.
I'm considering dropping the index and seeing if that helps but I don't know what damage that will do to my database and I don't know how to recreate it.

**UPDATE:** I copied the database and dropped the index using the sqlite command line utility and the sql command `DROP INDEX tasks_activity_provider_id_1557b363`.  I got the same problem with a different index.  I dropped that, too and then the migration worked!  It has re-created those indexes (according to the output from the sqlite command `.indexes`).  I would very much like to understand what is going on here if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you already run the migration, but then the migration's data was somehow lost on the migrations table?

Comment: This was the first time running the migration, so I don't think it could be that.  It's almost as if two of the sqlite indexes randomly became read-only somehow, or locked, so that the migration couldn't rebuild it (if that's what it was trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied migrations folder from an existing folder to a new folder. The migrations were already run. The migration file also added index with a name. When I copied the migrations folder to this new folder and tried running `python manage.py migrate`, it errored out because in the db, there was already an index with the same name.

Resolution: Just change the name of the index in the new migrations files!

This was a part of migrations file. Note that this file already existed and I created another copy and then tried running it again.

```
migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='slackinstallation',
            index=models.Index(fields=['client_id', 'enterprise_id', 'team_id', 'user_id', 'installed_at'], name='slack_bot_s_client__63314d_idx'),
        ),
```

Changing the name of the index to anything different worked. Just for reference, I modified the name like this:

```
migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='slackinstallation',
            index=models.Index(fields=['client_id', 'enterprise_id', 'team_id', 'user_id', 'installed_at'], name='slack_bot_v2_s_client__63314d_idx'),
        ),
```